# Deserialization error when passing JSON object to .NET WCF Service

Tags: .net, json, wcf, deserialization

I have an app in which I return JSON objects to the browser; JavaScript then that object and assigns it to a local variable. I can now interact with this object by reading and writing it it's properties. I can also make AJAX service calls where the WCF service methods parameters are all simple types. All of this works just fine; however, now that I have created a save method that takes a parameter of type BorrowerSummaryInfo (the same object that I initially received from the server and set to the local variable). This is .NET class declared with the DataContract attribute. My issue is that the object fails deserialization. I can't figure our why this is happening.

I am passing my object using the JSON.stringify method, and using jQuery's ajax functionality. I've tried letting .NET handle the deserialization, I've tried passing the string version where I attempted to deserialize it using both the DataContractJsonSerializer object and again with the JavaScriptSerializer. I've also made changes to the web.config to ensure that the size of the object is not the issue.

This concept is pretty straight forward, but nothing is working. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is the JSON object..

```
"{
    "Entity":"{
        '__type':'BorrowerSummaryInfo:StoneWaterUI',
        'ApplicationID':123,
        'BorrowerDetails':{
            '__type':'BorrowerDetailsInfo:StoneWaterUI'
            ,'Age':80,
            'BorrowerID':345,
            'DateOfBirth':'00/13/1931',
            'FirstName':'HERMINE',
            'HomePhone':'000-000-0000
            'IsPrimaryBorrower':false,
            'LastName':'DLESK',
            'MiddleName':'E.',
            'MobilePhone':'',
            'SSN':'000-00000
            'Suffix':'',
            'WorkPhone':'000-000-0000'
        },
        'CoBorrowerDetails':{
            '__type':'BorrowerDetailsInfo:StoneWaterUI',
            'Age':null,
            'BorrowerID':null,
            'DateOfBirth':'',
            'FirstName':'test',
            'HomePhone':'test1',
            'IsPrimaryBorrower':false,
            'LastName':'',
            'MiddleName':'',
            'MobilePhone':'',
            'SSN':'',
            'Suffix':'',
            'WorkPhone':''
        },
        'LoanID':55555
    }"
}"
```

Comment: You have single-quotes in there denoting property names. That's not valid.

Comment: You are absolutely correct; I glossed right over that. Thanks for your help!